# Utilizar variable con librería NCalc, VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

Buen día, esta pregunta es para VB.NET 2010 en una aplicación Windows Form.

Le agregue a mi proyecto la biblioteca NCalc.

Un ejemplo de un código muy simple utilizando dicha biblioteca.

```
    Dim expr = New Expression("[X] = 5")
    expr.Parameters("X") = 5

    If expr.Evaluate Then
        MsgBox("El nro es igual ")
    else
        MsgBox("Los nros no son iguales")
    End If
```

Si quisiera evaluar dos o más condiciones seria algo como:

```
    Dim expr = New Expression("[X] > 3.2 and [X] < 5.6")
    expr.Parameters("X") = 10
    If expr.Evaluate Then
        **acciones**
    End If
```

Y ahora viene la pregunta, como haría para poder reconocer una variable (que ya fue creada en tiempo de diseño).

Por ejemplo me gustaría comparar la variable AUX1. (Se que el código esta mal, es una mera representación de lo que me gustaría hacer)

```
Dim aux1 as Integer = 5
Dim expr = New Expression("[X] = aux1")
expr.Parameters("X") = 10
If expr.Evaluate Then
    **acciones**
End If
```

Alguien sabe como realizar esta acción? 
Espero sus respuestas! Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que simplemente deberías utilizar dos parámetros en la expresión:

```
Dim aux1 as Integer = 5
Dim expr = New Expression("[X] = [Y]")
expr.Parameters("X") = 10
expr.Parameters("Y") = aux1
If expr.Evaluate Then
    **acciones**
End If
```

O crear la expresión dinámicamente:

```
Dim aux1 as Integer = 5
Dim expr = New Expression("[X] = " & aux1.ToString())
expr.Parameters("X") = 10
If expr.Evaluate Then
    **acciones**
End If
```